# Is there a ESLint rule to prevent `Promise<boolean>` to `boolean` cast

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, eslint

I want a rule to prevent a `Promise<boolean>` from being cast to a `boolean`:

```
// ERROR: This is always true because it is a promise
if( !authorize() ){
  throw new Error('Go away!');
}
```

Correct:

```
// Good, only true if the promise result is true
if( !await authorize() ){
  throw new Error('Go away!');
}
```

Given something like this:

```
async authorize(){
  // I don't really support bribery
  return await doesUserHaveCredentials() || didUserPayMeABunchOfMoney();
}
```

Rules I have tried:

- require-await: Seems a good name for this, but this rule just checks if an async function contains an await somewhere
- @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises: Helpful, but doesn't prevent the boolean cast
- @typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions: Doesn't help in this case

Is anyone aware of a rule that would error on `if(!promise())`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want the `checkConditionals` option (which is enabled by default) in [`@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md):

> Examples of **incorrect** code for this rule with `checksConditionals: true`:
>
> ```
> const promise = Promise.resolve('value');
>
> if (promise) {
>   // Do something
> }
> ```

Comment: Perfect! Don't know how I missed that.